# OPA | Conftest incorrect parse yaml file

Tags: go, kubernetes, opa, open-policy-agent, conftest

ResourceQuota object definition involves limits keys with dots and there is issue to get the value of the limits:

policy.rego

```
package main

deny_incorrect_memory_unit[msg] {
  input.kind == "ResourceQuota"
  memoryLimit := input.spec.hard.limits.memory

  not regex.match("^[0-9]+M$", memoryLimit)
  msg := sprintf("%s: Incorrect value %s. Memory Limit in ResourceQuota must be defined in Megabytes (M) unit", [input.metadata.namespace, memoryLimit])
}
```

resource-quota.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: backend
spec:
  hard:
    pods: 1
    limits.cpu: 3
    limits.memory: "1G"
```

In above example test finishes with success, despite of wrong unit in limits.memory
After replacing yaml file to the below structure (which are not supported by k8s) test finish with expected result - failure:

```
spec:
  hard:
    pods: 1
    limits:
        cpu: 3
        memory: "1G"
```

Comment: You can check the content of input.spec.hard and check then how to retrieve limits.memory, maybe using memoryLimit := input.spec.hard[2]

Comment: Hackerman Thanks, you gave me food for thought. I found solution. I need use `input.spec.hard["limits.memory"]`